# My frame is empty regardless of what I try

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, calculator

I cannot get anything to show up in my frame anymore, can someone tell my why?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Calculator
{
    private final static int DIMENSION = 400;
    JFrame calcFrame;
    JPanel buttonPanel;
    JButton addButton;
    JButton subButton;
    JButton multButton;
    JButton divButton;
    JPanel resultPanel;
    JLabel resultLable;
    JLabel resultLabel;
    JTextField leftOperand;
    JTextField rightOperand;
    JLabel jlResult;
    JPanel textPanel;

    public Calculator()
    {
        calcFrame = new JFrame();
        calcFrame.setLocation(100, 100);
        calcFrame.setSize(DIMENSION, DIMENSION);
        calcFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        calcFrame.setTitle("Simple Calculator");

        initializeComponents();

        calcFrame.pack();
        calcFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public void initializeComponents()
    {
        addButton = new JButton("ADD");
        addButton.setName("addButton");

        subButton = new JButton("SUB");
        subButton.setName("subButton");

        multButton = new JButton("MULT");
        multButton.setName("multButton");

        divButton = new JButton("DIV");
        divButton.setName("divButton");

        resultLabel = new JLabel(" ");
        resultLabel.setName("resultLabel");

        jlResult = new JLabel("Result = ");
        jlResult.setName("jlResult");

        leftOperand = new JTextField(10);
        leftOperand.setName("leftOperand");

        rightOperand = new JTextField(10);
        rightOperand.setName("rightOperand");     


        Panel();
        addActionListeners();
    }
    public void Panel()
    {
        buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        resultPanel = new JPanel();
        textPanel = new JPanel();

        buttonPanel.add(addButton);
        buttonPanel.add(subButton);
        buttonPanel.add(multButton);
        buttonPanel.add(divButton);
        resultPanel.add(jlResult);
        resultPanel.add(resultLable);
        textPanel.add(leftOperand);
        textPanel.add(rightOperand);

        calcFrame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        calcFrame.add(resultPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        calcFrame.add(textPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

    }

    public void addActionListeners()
    {
        multButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                multClicked();
            }
        });
        divButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                divClicked();
            }
        });
        addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                addClicked();
            }
        });
        subButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                subClicked();
            }
        });
    }

    public JFrame getFrame()
    {
        return calcFrame;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Calculator calc = new Calculator();
    }
}
```

Comment: In your method `Panel()`. Change `resultPanel.add(resultLable);` to `resultPanel.add(resultLabel);`. `resultLable` isn't initialized therefore it was throwing nullpointerexception.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. 1) Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. 2) Instead of copy-pasting the same text 4-5 times to get rid of the text-code ratio error to post your question, describe what the error is, what exactly you did before it didn't show anything anymore, etc, the more information you provide, the easier it is to help you. 3) Indent your code correctly (I already fixed it), this helps us to detect errors easier (and you to prevent them).

Comment: 4) `pack()` is overriding the size returned by `setSize(...)`, remove 1 of them. 5) method names should start with a verb and with the first word `lowerCased` Please check [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) for more information about this. This point along with (3) will help you a LOT to improve your code-quality and reduce the number of errors you make as well as your code readability.

Comment: @Frakcool *"4) pack() is overriding the size returned by setSize(...), remove 1 of them."* Remove the 2nd. Setting the size of a component should be avoided in favor of making the component (actually) larger using a larger font, insets etcetera.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I swear I had written "remove 1 of them (suggest the 2nd), probably I got distracted with my own code that finished compiling and forgot that, thanks for complementing my comment :)

Answer (score 1):

This issue in your code is this line.

```
resultPanel.add(resultLable);
```

In you initializeComponents() method. You didn't initialize `resultLable`. Instead you have initialized

```
 resultLabel = new JLabel(" ");
 resultLabel.setName("resultLabel");

// You can also do this to initialize a label with a string
// resultLabel = new JLabel("resultLabel");
```

You can either change `resultPanel.add(resultLable);` to `resultPanel.add(resultLabel);`

or initialize `resultLable` in `initializeComponents()`